# Retrieve xml payment response and extract data with JSF/JQuery

Tags: java, jquery, http, post, httpurlconnection

I'm configuring a payment gateway which functions via xml to my Java Spring JSF facelets web application.The payment request must be sent to the gateway as a xml request, I've managed to send the xml payment request to the payment gateway.Suppose the xml response is coming back to the same page which I originated the payment request,

I want to know how to retrieve the response xml from the payment gateway?.

I've used the below method to send the request to payment gateway and it is successful,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#payForm').trigger('submit');
});

<form id="payForm" action="https://www.paymentGateway.com/gateway.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="request" value="#{paymentBean.request}"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Checkout the 9th example here: [link]http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: if want to use AJAX would have to send form data to your server and have it post to gateway and return the response from gateway in AJAX

Comment: I already know that method, but I prefer a different mechanism @charlietfl

Comment: In ajax method suppose this is posted to external url, it will give cross domain ajax errors

Comment: you can't send POST cross domain in AJAX which is why you need to use proxy on your server

Comment: @Swarnajith try with Ajax callback